# WinHttp: Kill its working thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I used a winHttp in my program to access the internet.
My question is:

During closing(exiting) of the program, if there is still some un-finished WinHttp sync request, do I need to wait until they properly finished?

Or I could just kill their running threads directly and quit the program?

If I wait for the unfinished WinHttp request, sometimes it could take 10+ seconds for them to finish.